# Compiling returns missing methods and packages from Swing's JFrame class in Java

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jframe

This code will return three errors on NetBeans for these lines:

```
leftPanel.setLayout (leftBox );
leftPanel.add (optionBar);
leftPanel.add (tabBar);
leftPanel.add (paintArea);
rightPanel.setLayout (rightBox);
rightPanel.add (toolbar);
rightPanel.add (toolArea);
```

It returns:

```
package rightPanel does not exist

<identifier> expected

missing method body, or declare abstract

<identifier> expected
----
```

The program also has issues with this part:

```
setLayout(flo);

add(leftPanel);

add(rightPanel);
```

And returns:

invalid method declaration; return type required

I've tried searching and found information for all types of problems, but I can't find anything directly corresponding to my personal issue.

Here's the full code:

```
package level.builder;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class LevelBuilderGUI extends JFrame {

    //Version For the Title
    private static String version = "Alpha";

    //Creating leftmost panel
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout leftBox = new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

    leftPanel.setLayout (leftBox );
    JPanel optionBar = new JPanel();

    leftPanel.add (optionBar);
    JPanel tabBar = new JPanel();

    leftPanel.add (tabBar);
    JPanel paintArea = new JPanel();

    leftPanel.add (paintArea);

    //Creating rightmost panel
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout rightBox = new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

    rightPanel.setLayout (rightBox);
    JPanel toolBar = new JPanel();

    rightPanel.add (toolbar);
    JPanel toolArea = new JPanel();

    rightPanel.add (toolArea);

    //Putting it all together
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();

    setLayout(flo);

    add(leftPanel);

    add(rightPanel);

    public LevelBuilderGUI() {
        super();
        setTitle("Level Builder version" + version);
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(512, 128);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel);");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me understand my mistake.

Edit: Thanks for all of the help, I see that the issue I had was putting all of the code outside of a method. The code now runs after being moved into the constructor.

Comment: Most of the code should be enclosed by a constructor or method.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem(s) you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try put all these lines you are getting the error inside the constructor. You are getting those errors because you are calling methods for the attributes on the "body" of your class, outside any encapsulation.

Piece of advice here: check the visibility for your attributes, it's never a good practice let them free like that. ;)